# Pointer declaration syntax

Tags: c++

What is the difference between

```
Simple_window*  sw
```

and

```
Simple_window  *sw
```

where simple window is just class and sw is an object created from that class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference based on the position of the `*` character.

Some people will say that

```
Simple_window* sw
```

is superior because it associates the pointer indicator `*` with the typename `Simple_window` to give the real type: `Simple_window*`, i.e. "Pointer to Simple_window".

Other people say that it is better to put the `*` close-up against the variables, since C++ will interpret it only for the next variable.  That is,

```
Simple_window* sw, anotherSw
```

actually declares `sw` as a pointer, and `anotherSw` as a non-pointer `Simple_window` object!  Because of this, the close-against-variable version might better indicate intent when using multiple declarations.

```
Simple_window *sw, *anotherSw
```

Because of this issue, I make it a habit not to use single-line declarations of multiple objects.

I prefer the first version, agreeing with the description I once read that it is more "C++-like".

Comment: No *semantical* difference, at least. There *is* stylistic difference, and arguably the one can be preferred over the other.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much difference except

```
Simple_window*  sw
```

means you are defining a variable of the type `Simple_window*` whereas

```
Simple_window  *sw
```

means you are defining a pointer of the type `Simple_window`, both of them basically are pointers.

The difference arises, when you are defining multiple variables together, for example:

```
int* x, y, z;
```

implies that x, y and z are all pointers, which they are not (only x is).
The second version does not have this problem:

```
int *x, y, z;
```

In other words, since the * binds to the variable name and not the type, it makes sense to place it right next to the variable name.